# Add Lock cells / ranges to an existing VBA code to create editable areas and allow VBA to run

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't used VBA  before so I'm really new to this :-) The below is the code I am currently using , and simply need to lock all area's of the sheet (with out using the sheet name) apart from A13:A377, B1, D3:D4, D13:D377, F13:I377. I can't protect the sheet because the VBA won't work. Help please...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 1 Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & " & " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Locking has no effect if you don't protect the sheet.

Comment: This is exactly the same code as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1726776/ambiguous-name-detected-worksheet-change-when-adding-2-change-events/1726963#1726963) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599360/ambiguous-name-detected-worksheet-change-when-adding-2-change-events).  Those questions weren't about locking cells though, but about an ambiguous name detected and having a multi-select drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

### unlock cells and protect sheet

I don't see any relation between your description and the code you have shared! Please find below a proposal to unlock a union of cells and protect the sheet (without password!)

```
Option Explicit

Sub UnlockCells_and_Protect()
Dim actSheet As String
        
    actSheet = "Sheet2"    ' choose whatever you need
    'actSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    'actSheet = Sheets(3).Name
    'actsheet = "SpecialSheet"
    
Call UnprotectSheet(actSheet)
Call LockAll(actSheet)
Call UnlockRange(actSheet, "A13:A377,B1,D3:D4,D13:D377,F13:I377")

Call ProtectSheet(actSheet)
    
End Sub

Sub UnlockRange(sheetName As String, RangeReference As String)
    With Sheets(sheetName).Range(RangeReference)
        .Locked = False
        .FormulaHidden = False
        
        'you might want to mark the unlocked cells for debugging
        Sheets(sheetName).Range(RangeReference).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With
End Sub

Sub ProtectSheet(sheetName As String)
    Sheets(sheetName).Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub

Sub ProtectActiveSheet()
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub

Sub UnprotectSheet(sheetName As String)
    Sheets(sheetName).Unprotect
End Sub

Sub UnprotectActiveSheet()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
End Sub

Sub LockAll(sheetName As String)
    Sheets(sheetName).Cells.Locked = True
    Sheets(sheetName).Cells.FormulaHidden = False
    
    'if you marked the unlocked cells yellow you change
    'them back to white with lock/unlock all
    Sheets(sheetName).Cells.Interior.Color = vbWhite
End Sub

Sub UnlockAll(sheetName As String)
    Sheets(sheetName).Cells.Locked = False
    Sheets(sheetName).Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    
    'if you marked the unlocked cells yellow you change
    'them back to white with lock/unlock all
    Sheets(sheetName).Cells.Interior.Color = vbWhite
End Sub
```